# What Japanese lullabys are available to provide early Japanese exposure to children?

Tags: learning, resources, phonetics, music

I'd like to expose my young children to the sounds of Japanese at night as they go to sleep.
Specifically, I'd like to play Japanese lullabies or other soothing music with vocals. Where do I find such music?

Comment: For what it’s worth, “lullaby” is [子守歌]{こもりうた} (also written as 子守唄) in Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know a children's song, かえるのうた (The Frog's Song, The Frog Song)
I'm not sure if you'd classify it as a lullaby, but it has a simple melody and can even be sung in a round (I think of it as the Japanese "Row, Row, Row your Boat")

Here's a link: [Frog Song](http://thejapanesepage.com/audio/kaeru_no_uta)

Note: There seems to be a regional difference where the line "Gero gero gero gero" is replaced with "Kiki kiki kiki kiki".

Enjoy!

Comment: (1) I think that the title of this song is かえるの合唱, although I do not have an evidence better than that there are many webpages referring to it as かえるの合唱 (which is arguably a poor evidence…).  (2) I would not count かえるの合唱 as a lullaby, but it is difficult to define a clear border.  I imagine that some parents may sing it at night to put their children to sleep, and there is nothing wrong with it.